# Get value from session on every method of every controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some controller and in each method of each controller I have next code:

```
@user = session[:user]
```

Is there a way to avoid putting this code on every method of each controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your code in `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :current_user

  def current_user
    @user = session[:user]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The anwer of @nash is fine, and here is an alternative providing helper methods you can use in every method/view. This is the way gems like Devise go:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  helper_method :current_user
  helper_method :user_signed_in?

  private  
    def current_user  
      @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]  
    end

    def user_signed_in?
      return 1 if current_user 
    end

    def authenticate_user!
      if !current_user
        flash[:error] = 'You need to sign in before accessing this page!'
        redirect_to signin_services_path
      end
    end  
end
```